# Boolean for whether a number is in a range

Tags: filemaker

Suppose I have a variable `$$Range` which is inputted as either a range (e.g. *1..2*).

Can I write a boolean which is true if `$$Number` is in the range `$$Range`, and false otherwise?

*E.g. $$Number is 1 and $$Range is 1..2 should return True, and $$Number is 4 and $$Range is 1..2 should return False.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convenience `Set Variable [$$range2; Substitute($$Range;["..";" "];["...";" "]) ]`

Then, the required boolean is:

```
RightWords($$range2;1) <= $$Number & $$Number < RightWords($$range2;2)
```

Comment: This seems a round-about/long method!